# Кириллица в javascript

Tags: javascript

Почему текст кириллицы, который был написан в javascript коде, отображается квадратиками?

```
var anwer = prompt('Вы уверины что хотите сюда нажать?');

if (anwer) {
    document.write(anwer);
}
else {
    document.write('он стеснительный');
}
```

Comment: код покажите

Comment: Добавлено в вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

charset какой стоит у станицы? Надо windows-1251.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <title>Ваш тайтл</title>
 </head>
 <body>
тут Ваш скрипт
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: где его посмотреть?

Comment: Добавлено в ответ.

Comment: `windows-1251` не обязательно тех-же результатов можно достичь и с `utf-8` :-)

Comment: естественно можно. Нужно текст в утф кодировке, я думаю вопрос не о том